# R : How to split the accumulated value to missing values in data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I'm still new to R. From this example table, you can clearly see that there are some accumulated values on diff column. So how to spread these values to NA values that occurs accumulating many rows into a row because my devices have a problem in recording value getting missing value in some hours but they still can get the right value in next coming hour.

My example data :

```
                                 DateTime diff1  diff2
1                     2017-06-11 05:00:00   366   25   
2                     2017-06-11 06:00:00   380   22   
3                     2017-06-11 07:00:00   365   40   
4                     2017-06-11 08:00:00   366   45   
5                     2017-06-11 09:00:00   361   91  
6                     2017-06-11 10:00:00   1782  NA
7                     2017-06-11 11:00:00   NA    46  
8                     2017-06-11 12:00:00   NA    44  
9                     2017-06-11 13:00:00   NA    89  
10                    2017-06-11 14:00:00   NA    NA  
11                    2017-06-11 15:00:00   345   46
```

I had to set manual condition if it is greater than a value (about 1000 or whatever), it will be deleted and changed to approx value. But it is the worst idea by my stupid. This not work for my whole data (about 1k rows or more) just work for a little example. I don't know how to fix it and set the best condition to filter and fill properly value to get more wisely data preparation before fill value.

The output should be like this :

```
binning by mean of accumulated value              
                                 DateTime diff1 diff2  
1                     2017-06-11 05:00:00 366.0  25.0   
2                     2017-06-11 06:00:00 380.0  22.0     
3                     2017-06-11 07:00:00 365.0  40.0       
4                     2017-06-11 08:00:00 366.0  45.0        
5                     2017-06-11 09:00:00 361.0  45.5       
6                     2017-06-11 10:00:00 356.4  45.5            
7                     2017-06-11 11:00:00 356.4  46.0      
8                     2017-06-11 12:00:00 356.4  44.0      
9                     2017-06-11 13:00:00 356.4  44.5       
10                    2017-06-11 14:00:00 356.4  44.5        
11                    2017-06-11 15:00:00 345.0  46.0
[OR] by na.approx()          
                                 DateTime    diff1    diff2
1                     2017-06-11 05:00:00 366.0000 25.00000
2                     2017-06-11 06:00:00 380.0000 22.00000
3                     2017-06-11 07:00:00 365.0000 40.00000
4                     2017-06-11 08:00:00 366.0000 45.00000
5                     2017-06-11 09:00:00 361.0000 45.33333
6                     2017-06-11 10:00:00 358.3333 45.66667
7                     2017-06-11 11:00:00 355.6667 46.00000
8                     2017-06-11 12:00:00 353.0000 44.00000
9                     2017-06-11 13:00:00 350.3333 44.66667
10                    2017-06-11 14:00:00 347.6667 45.33333
11                    2017-06-11 15:00:00 345.0000 46.00000
```

The most point I need is to filter these accumulated values changed to NA wisely. 
Any idea please help. Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution:

```
df[c('diff1', 'diff2')] <- lapply(df[c('diff1', 'diff2')], function(x){
    g <- cumsum(!is.na(x))
    ave(x, g, FUN = function(y) y[1] / length(y))
})

# > df
#               DateTime diff1 diff2
# 1  2017-06-11 05:00:00 366.0  25.0
# 2  2017-06-11 06:00:00 380.0  22.0
# 3  2017-06-11 07:00:00 365.0  40.0
# 4  2017-06-11 08:00:00 366.0  45.0
# 5  2017-06-11 09:00:00 361.0  45.5
# 6  2017-06-11 10:00:00 356.4  45.5
# 7  2017-06-11 11:00:00 356.4  46.0
# 8  2017-06-11 12:00:00 356.4  44.0
# 9  2017-06-11 13:00:00 356.4  44.5
# 10 2017-06-11 14:00:00 356.4  44.5
# 11 2017-06-11 15:00:00 345.0  46.0
```

`dput` of the original data I used:

```
sample.df <- structure(list(DateTime = c("2017-06-11 05:00:00", "2017-06-11 06:00:00", 
"2017-06-11 07:00:00", "2017-06-11 08:00:00", "2017-06-11 09:00:00", 
"2017-06-11 10:00:00", "2017-06-11 11:00:00", "2017-06-11 12:00:00", 
"2017-06-11 13:00:00", "2017-06-11 14:00:00", "2017-06-11 15:00:00"
), diff1 = c(366L, 380L, 365L, 366L, 361L, 1782L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 345L), diff2 = c(25L, 22L, 40L, 45L, 91L, NA, 46L, 44L, 89L, 
NA, 46L)), .Names = c("DateTime", "diff1", "diff2"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But can I get only filter removing the accumulated value changed to NA part? I want to try it with `na.approx()` from package `zoo`.

Comment: @SirawitTakeo, I have no previous experience with `na.approx`. i tried a lttle bit just now but could find a way to get desired results.

Comment: It's not that much close to the true values as it should be but it's great smooth on plot so much.